# Rendering LabelFor doesn't display the overwritten getter function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

pardon me if this is a noob question but I have already searched on SO, google, and spend over an hour with an ASP.NET MVC 4 PRO book reading on Rendering Stronly Typed Helpers etc. I am just beginning learning ASP.NET 4 MVC so please go easy on me.

I have a model class called `USER` and a property called `Name` with an overwritten getter and setter (its me calling it this way, im not sure if this is the proper naming in the case)

```
//using...

namespace MvcMyApplication1.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
            }
            set
            {
                Name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
            }
        }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Password is required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So, In my `View` I am trying to display the result of the `get` function, but I am lost and  not sure how to do this.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors: true);
    // changed from LabelFor to DisplayFor
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)<br />
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
}
```

I have tried to add attributes but then I am not sure how to assign the `Name=` to the `get` function

```
  [DisplayName(Name="I want to call the get function here")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
```

In my controller I have this code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            User newUser = new User();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(User m)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Report", m);
            }
            {
                return View(m);
            }
        }
```

And this goes to the `Report` View
which normally displays the `Windows login`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DisplayForModel()
}
```

**EDIT:**
 After swapping the `LabelFor` with `DisplayFor` the windows login is rendered but only after clicking the **log in** button. It does not render the first time I open the page

Comment: your setter is both redundant and an infite recursion. You are trying to assign a value to the property, which will call the property setter and start the loop all over ending in a infite recursion. Since you are never using the value set by the setter (even if it could set a value) you don't need the setter at all

Comment: @RuneFS i was thinking the same thing thanks to you im sure of it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing in the model to the initial view:

```
return View();
```

should be

```
return View(newUser);
```

Comment: And on a side note, it doesn't make sense to me to even have a property where the setter doesn't use the value you pass in... rather make it a normal property and always set it to the windows user name, outside of the model's own code?

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean in point 4 and 3. And @jamiebarrow is right, you should return the model in the initial view. This will definitely fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, give me a few minutes to try it all out and research the topics i havent come across yet in this asp.net adventure :) thanks for your patience

Comment: @jamiebarrow this is it! it really was a noob question. thank you very much for solving it

Comment: @mehow Sure thing, and don't worry, it happens to non-noobs too ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `DisplayFor` **not** `LabelFor` if you want to retrieve the property value.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I have tried that. It displays an empty label. Oh, and I just have noticed it does display the windows login, but only after clicking the `log in` button

Comment: @mehow Put a breakpoint in that set and make sure it's returning an actual value.

Comment: I put a breakpoint, but as I am just beginning im not yet sure where (which window in VB2012) I can preview the value

Comment: @mehow Use the Watch window

Comment: I was just reading how to use the debug in VB2012 express sorry for the delay. It seems like the first time the View() is rendered there is no value at all -> unless im doing something wrong...

Comment: your answer is very helpful so +1 definitely although besides the DisplayFor I wasnt passing the model into the first view. thank you both for help

Answer (score 0):

1. To get current authenticated user in the view, you can use @User.Identity.Name.
   In controller, use User.Identity.Name
2. To display "I want to call the get function here" in DisplayName attribute in the view, use @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => model.Name)
3. Use WindowsIdentity in your class is not a good idea. For MVC, better use User.Identity.Name (use this in controller), the reason is this way it is get the user name under current HttpRequest, use WindowsIdentity might be fine, but careful. Depending on how you use it, it might return error or return the service account which ran the application pool.
4. Normally, getter and setter are written like this by calling a private property:

   public class User{

   ```
     private string _name;

     public string Name
   {
       get{
           return _name;
       }
       set{
           _name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
       }

   }
   ```
5. It looks like your MVC app is using Windows Authentication, which is an intranet app, so your user will be automatically authenticated, which means logged on already.

Comment: thanks for the answer. however, its not an intranet app and i am not authenticating the user based on the windows login - the login only supplies the user's username for me ( internal application ) and each username is already stored in a database with ad ID and Name ( unique windows logins ). Again, its an internal app im developing. So the authentication in this app has to be developed based on the custom needs. You can think of the DisplayFor(m => m.Name ) as if it only provides a `hello currently.logged.user.on.windows` - sort of in a welcome `ur_name` to the website.

Comment: Under the hood that `Name` will be used as user's login but they still have to supply password to match the database records. I hope this clears it all out. **The problem** still remains unsolved to me because the `DisplayFor` does not render the value unless a `POST` back has been executed.

Comment: So have you tried to use this? "To get current authenticated user in the view, you can use @User.Identity.Name. In controller, use User.Identity.Name" Will this not satisfied what you are after?

Comment: thanks for the tips. I havent tried it yet as I am not sure what you mean. I am researching User.Identity.Name now.